# Improving this continuous jQuery animation

Tags: jquery, animation, effect, continuous

I've just created a simple, continuous [bounce effect](http://jsfiddle.net/pkn9F/2/) in jQuery but I feel the code isn't all that optimized and am looking to improve it.

```
var $square = $("#square");
bounce();
function bounce() {
    $square.animate({
        top: "+=10"
    }, 300, function() {
        $square.animate({
            top: "-=10"
        }, 300, function() {
            bounce();
        })
    });
}

$square.hover(function() {        
    jQuery.fx.off = true;
}, function() {
    jQuery.fx.off = false;
});
```

All I've done is basically created an animation that adds +10 to the top coordinate of the element, and as a callback function, I'm subtracting 10 from the top coordinate..

This creates an (almost smooth) bounce effect but I feel it can be improved.

Furthermore, I want to stop the animation on `mouseenter`, and have it continue on `mouseleave`.

`stop(true, true)` didn't work, neither did `dequeue()` so I've resorted to turning all animation effects off using `jQuery.fx.off = true` (stupid, no?)

I'd appreciate any feedback on how this can be optimized.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pkn9F/2/).

**EDIT: I've just realized that jQuery has started throwing `too much recursion` errors when disabling and re-enabling the effects.**

Thanks in advance,

Marko

Comment: I guess, by calling bounce() within itself as callback, generates a large stack trace and thus results in a too much recursion error.

Comment: The problem with too much recursion is that there is too much recursion.

Comment: Yes @Neil - and in order to understand recursion, you must first understand recursion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try the below code  Demo : **http://jsfiddle.net/LMXPX/**

```
$(function() {
    var $square = $("#square"),flag = -1;
    var timer = bounce = null;
    (bounce = function () {
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            flag = ~flag + 1;
            $square.animate({ 
                top: "+="+(flag*10)
            }, 300)
        },300);
    })();                
    $square.hover(function() {        
        clearInterval(timer);
    }, function() {
        bounce();
    });
});
```

Edit : I guess in your code multiple CallBack functions are the reason for too much recursion

Comment: So without the callback, is there another way to continuously loop the animation?

Comment: **smacks head** sorry, it's 9am and I just woke up :) That works perfectly, accepting.

Answer (score 0):

Not much of an improvement but here's my attempt:

```
var $square = $("#square");

(function loop () {
    $square
        .animate({ top: "+=10" }, 300)
        .animate({ top: "-=10" }, 300, loop );
})();

$square.hover(function() {
    $.fx.off = !$.fx.off;
});
```

​

Comment: At first I thought of writing the same code, But it resulted in too much recursion, callBack function is the reason for too much recursion :(